# Gtk SpinButtion in a Toolbar

Tags: gnome, programming, gtk, application-development

How do I place a SpinButton widget on a Toolbar using GTK, or GTKmm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gtkToolbar accept any gktWidget, like any other container. An example in python:
`import gtk

root = gtk.Window()
toolbar = gtk.Toolbar()
root.add(toolbar)

spinbutton = gtk.SpinButton()
toolbar.add(spinbutton)

root.show_all()
gtk.main()`
[image]

So this works just like adding the GtkToolbar to the GtkWindow.

Comment: Oh, sure, it inherits from gtk.Container. Thanks for quick tip!

Comment: By the way, is it possible to add it using gtk.UIManager?

Comment: I *think* it's not possible, but I don't know - I always use GtkBuilder and Glade instead.

Comment: Whoops. That does not work. It does compile, but running the application results with an error message in the stdio, stating that this is ToolBar's deprecated API.

Comment: Oh, got it to work. Had to add a ToolItem into the tooblar, then call toolitem.add(spinbutton).